# how to implement Equal Earth Projection in map and raster in R?

Tags: r, maps, gis, raster, proj

I wonder if anyone knows how to implement the Equal Earth Projection for a map and a raster in R?

I found this tutorial:

https://rud.is/b/2018/09/28/quick-hit-using-the-new-equal-earth-projection-in-r/

But I cannot replicate it. It seems the "+proj=eqearth" is not available, although it appears it should be by now.

```
library(rgdal)
library(maps)
library(maptools)


RobinsonProj="+proj=robin +lon_0=0 +x_0=0 +y_0=0 +ellps=WGS84 +datum=WGS84 +units=m +no_defs"
EqualEarthProj= "+proj=eqearth +lon_0=0 +x_0=0 +y_0=0 +ellps=WGS84 +datum=WGS84 +units=m +no_defs"
LatLonProj="+proj=longlat +datum=WGS84"

worldmap <- maps::map("world", plot=F,interior = F,wrap=c(-180,180))   #create map of the world
worldmapLines <- map2SpatialLines(worldmap, proj4string=CRS(LatLonProj))

#reproject
RobinsonMap <- spTransform(worldmapLines, CRS(RobinsonProj))
LatLonMap <- spTransform(worldmapLines, CRS(LatLonProj))
EqualEarthMap <- spTransform(worldmapLines, CRS(EqualEarthProj))
```

Answer (score 0):

That blogpost starts with saying "I noticed that proj4 had been updated to *5.2*"

But I assume that you are on windows and that when you do

```
library(rgdal)
```

You get

```
# Loaded PROJ.4 runtime: Rel. 4.9.3, 15 August 2016, [PJ_VERSION: 493]
```

And that explains it. Not at version 5.2 yet.

Comment: hmm, is there a way to call the most recent version?. the current version is 4 years old>

Comment: Not on windows, but you can easily run linux on windows these days (with the Windows Subsystem for Linux, WSL)